# Symbols and html tags conversion through PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

For example this is the string I have taken from the user in html form

Welcome to the
    **world**!

I want to store this value in database through PHP but encoding it i.e by converting the bold tag for example convert < to "& lt;"

If also the input consists of any special symbols like @ or ! It should also convert that to appropriate

Then after it is stored in database while receiving the values I want that values to be decoded i.e "& lt;" converted to < back again and respective the special symbols

Please do suggest any process through PHP

I have searched many sites but not got any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htmlentities()` on the way in to encode the HTML, and `html_entity_decode()` on the way out. More info on the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

```
htmlentities('<b>test</b>'); //would output: "<b>test</b>"

html_entity_decode('<b>test</b>'); //would output: "test" but bolded
```